# How can I changed users sql data, while he is offline?

Tags: php, html, sql, ajax

I am making online multiplayer browser game, where sql data load everytime page loads. I have code that refreshes page every 10 sec. So, my problem is that I want to change players sql data every 10 sec also when he is offline, for example, $row['x'] - 1, and do this 10 times. Someone said that I could get last time online and just calculate it with current time on their next login and then change variable, but I can't because every player can see other data.

Comment: You could do it as a job that runs in the background. Are you using a PHP Framework, like symfony or laravel?

Comment: I am using just php and sql and also ajax

Comment: i guess you would need to have a page open somewhere else that reloads itself every 10 seconds and performs any operations you would need. A special admin page or something. My recommendation would be to utilize a framework that allows you to process background jobs at specific intervals